# idiom for protecting against inexact native division in code that uses sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

I am developing some code whose variables and function params are
sometimes native python numeric types (int, float)
and sometimes sympy types
(sympy.core.numbers.Integer, sympy.core.numbers.Rational, sympy.core.symbol.Symbol,
sympy.core.add.Add, etc.).
And I sometimes want to express division (/),
but I'm having trouble finding a non-error-prone way to express it.

Here is some very simple representative example code, which works fine, until it doesn't:

```
import sympy

def MyAverageOfThreeNumbers(a, b, c):
  return (a + b + c) / 3

print(MyAverageOfThreeNumbers(0, 1, 2))
# 1.0
print(type(MyAverageOfThreeNumbers(0, 1, 2)))
#<class 'float'>

print(MyAverageOfThreeNumbers(sympy.Integer(0), 1, 2))
# 1
print(type(MyAverageOfThreeNumbers(sympy.Integer(0), 1, 2)))
#<class 'sympy.core.numbers.One'>

x = sympy.symbols("x")
print(MyAverageOfThreeNumbers(x, 1, 2))
# x/3 + 1
print(type(MyAverageOfThreeNumbers(x, 1, 2)))
# <class 'sympy.core.add.Add'>
print(MyAverageOfThreeNumbers(x, x, x))
# x
print(type(MyAverageOfThreeNumbers(x, x, x)))
# <class 'sympy.core.symbol.Symbol'>
```

So far so good; but then...

```
print(MyAverageOfThreeNumbers(1, 1, 2))
# 1.3333333333333333   <-- bad!  I want 4/3
print(type(MyAverageOfThreeNumbers(1, 1, 2)))
# <class 'float'>  <-- bad!  I want sympy.core.numbers.Rational or equivalent

print(sympy.Rational(MyAverageOfThreeNumbers(1, 1, 2)))
# 6004799503160661/4503599627370496  <-- bad!  I want 4/3
print(type(sympy.Rational(MyAverageOfThreeNumbers(1, 1, 2))))
# <class 'sympy.core.numbers.Rational'>
```

Solutions I've considered:

(1) Whenever I type '/' in my code,
make sure at least one of the operands is a sympy type rather than native.
E.g. one way to safely rewrite my function would be as follows:

```
      def MyAverageOfThreeNumbers(a, b, c):
        return (a + b + c) * sympy.core.numbers.One() / 3

      print(MyAverageOfThreeNumbers(1, 1, 2))
      # 4/3  <-- good!
```

(2) Avoid/prohibit use of '/' in my code entirely, except in this helper function:

```
      def MySafeDivide(a, b):
        return a * sympy.core.numbers.One() / b
```

(in fact I could avoid it there too, using [operator.truediv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.truediv) instead of the `/` operator).
Then I'd rewrite my function as:

```
      def MyAverageOfThreeNumbers(a, b, c):
        return MySafeDivide(a + b + c, 3)
```

(3) Whenever I write a function designed to accept both native types and sympy times,
always convert to sympy types at the beginning of the function body:
E.g. I'd rewrite my function as:

```
      def MyAverageOfThreeNumbers(a, b, c):
        # In case any or all of a,b,c are native types...
        a *= sympy.core.numbers.One()
        b *= sympy.core.numbers.One()
        c *= sympy.core.numbers.One()
        # Now a,b,c can be used safely in subsequent arithmetic
        # that may involve '/', without having to scrutinize the code too closely.
        return (a + b + c) / 3
```

All three of the above solutions seem ugly and (more importantly) error prone,
and they require me to periodically audit my code
to make sure I haven't mistakenly added any new unsafe uses of '/'.
Also, I'm finding that it's too tempting to leave the following very frequent
kind of expression as-is, since it's safe:

```
   some_python_expression/2
```

rather than rewriting it as one of:

```
   (some_python_expression * sympy.core.numbers.One()) / 2
```

or:

```
   MySafeDivide(some_python_expression, 2)
```

but then that makes my code harder to audit for mistakes,
since `some_python_expression/2` is safe but `some_python_expression/3` isn't.
(Nit: actually even `some_python_expression/2` isn't *completely* safe, e.g. `2**-1074/2` yields `0.0`)

So I'm looking for a robust maintainable solution that will bulletproof my code from this kind of mistake.  Ideally I'd like to either:

- consistently override '/' so that it always calls MySafeDivide() (see above) throughout my python file, or
- prohibit the use of '/' throughout my python file (ideally at compile time, but runtime would be better than nothing)

Are either of these things possible in python?
Note, I want to stick with standard python3 as the interpreter, which rules out solutions that require help from a nonstandard interpreter or compiler.

Comment: The `sympify` function is used for this. Convert the inputs to sympy types using sympify.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin sure, sympify works in place of `* One()`, thanks.  Still looking for a robust solution for preventing the accidental typing of e.g. `2/3`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a SymPy expression returned from a function and don't want to do anything hackish within the function, start by sympifying your arguments as Oscar has said:

```py
from sympy import sympify
def MyAverageOfThreeNumbers(a, b, c):
  a,b,c = map(sympify, (a,b,c))
  return (a + b + c) / 3
```

Your other idea (more hackish) of including a SymPy `One` as a factor before dividing is ok, too. You could make this into a function that can be used whenever you want to divide and get a SymPy result in return.

```py
def safe_div(a, b):
    return a*S.One/b
```

But the idea of being able to write expressions naturally and most transparently would favor the first method. You can think of that as clearly indicating at the start that you want a SymPy expression so you are making all inputs SymPy objects. And then the machinery of Python and SymPy allow you to use normal operators after that in a "safe" manner. The only time in subsequent code that you would have to be careful is when you try add a fraction to a number, e.g. `2/3 + x` would need to be written as `S(2)/3 + x` where `from sympy import S` has been executed.

Comment: Regarding sympify: good to know, thanks.  Regarding "The only time in subsequent code that you would have to be careful is when you try add a fraction to a number, e.g. `2/3 + x` would need to be written as "...  Right, this is really the entire point of the question.  The problem is that I end up typing `2/3 + x` no matter how careful I am, and then I have to debug it, which doesn't seem like time well spent.  So I'm looking for a reliable way to simply prohibit that.

Comment: An object can override an operator like `__div__` by defining its own `__div__` routine, but when you type `2/3` those are native python ints and I don't think you have control over what the div routine does with them. You can easily find such expressions with regular expression like `[0-9]/[1-9]` and you can just think of learning not to do that like learning to type `2**3` instead of `2^3` for exponentiation.

Comment: The regex doesn't really work (e.g. `x=2; y=3; print(x/y)`).  But I found a way to prohibit '/' entirely (unless the denominator is a literal power of 2), which is the only way I've found so far to prevent the mistake; I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to prohibit division in a python file, thus preventing the mistake in question:

```
import assert_division_operator_not_used_in_this_file
assert_division_operator_not_used_in_this_file.assert_division_operator_not_used_in_this_file()
```

where `assert_division_operator_not_used_in_this_file.py` contains:

```
import inspect
import ast
def assert_division_operator_not_used_in_this_file():
  caller_frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
  caller_module = inspect.getmodule(caller_frame)
  caller_file_contents = inspect.getsource(caller_module)
  tree = ast.parse(caller_file_contents)
  for node in ast.walk(tree):
    assert not (type(node) == ast.BinOp and type(node.op) == ast.Div), f"{caller_frame.f_code.co_filename}({node.lineno}): forbidden operator '/' used!"
```

More nuanced implementations are possible, e.g. permit the division when the denominator is a literal (int or float) power of 2.